# word document opens minimized after mail merge using msaccess

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have the following code to perform a mail merge using VBA, after the mail merge is performed the word document opens minimized, is there a way to have the document opened as normal(maximized)?

```
Dim DocName As String
Echo -1, "Merge in progress..."



Dim templateName As String, tempRoot As String

tempRoot = "c:\temp\mailmerge"

templateName = tempRoot & "CertificateRSZDutch.dotx"

Dim objDoc As Word.Document

Dim objWord As New Word.Application

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(templateName)

objWord.Visible = True


DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Mailmerge_CertificateRSZDutch", "Q:\jas\hr\mailmerge\LES\CertificateRSZDutch.txt", True

objDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _

tempRoot & "CertificateRSZDutch.txt", ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly _

:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:= _

"", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _

WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _

Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _

wdMergeSubTypeOther


objDoc.MailMerge.Execute

objDoc.Close False

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs tempRoot & "CertificateRSZ.docx"

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=tempRoot & "CertificateRSZ.docx")


Set objWord = Nothing

Set objDoc = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use the code button - {} to format your post.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your program before opening the word document

```
Dim shell As New shell
shell.MinimizeAll
```

this will minimize all the opened applications windows

and put this code after opening the word document.

```
objWord.Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

this will maximize the word document to be opened.